# C#, Efficient way to fill an image with input parameters

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have a large image `img` of size 8192 * 8192, I have 3 matrices of size 4096 * 4096:

- Matrix `X` containing x pixel coordinates
- Matrix `Y` containing y pixel coordinates
- Matrix `RGB` containing RGB values

Foreach values in my matrices, I want to fill `img` at pixel x,y with rgb values.

Example:
*If X[0,0] = 500, Y[0,0] = 200 and RGB[0,0] = (255,0,0), big image[500,200] = (255,0,0)*

So far I have this

```
 public void Test()
 {
     Image<Bgr, byte> img = new(8196, 8192);

     //Parameter
     int size = 4096;
     Image<Gray, int> X = new(size, size);
     Image<Gray, int> Y = new(size, size);
     Image<Bgr, byte> rgb = new(size, size);
    
     //Timer
     Stopwatch cs = new Stopwatch();
     cs.Start();

     Parallel.For(0, size, i =>
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
         {
             int xTarget = (int)X[i, j].Intensity;
             int yTarget = (int)Y[i, j].Intensity;
             Bgr bgrTarget = rgb[i, j];

             img[xTarget, yTarget] = bgrTarget;

         }
     });

     cs.Stop();
     MessageBox.Show(cs.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
 }
```

Is there a more efficient way ?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a more efficient way ?

Not really. You need to process each X/Y pixel at least once, so you can not gain any algorithmic improvements.

There may be possible to get some micro optimizations. For example, When reading values from your X and Y images the code will convert the integer to a double and back again, possibly costing some performance. It might also be slightly faster to use unsafe code and pointers. But I'm not sure either issue could be fixed without moving away from emgu images. But I would expect this to be fairly minor improvements.

My main concern would be that the code is not deterministic. If there are any duplicate x and y coordinates there will not be a consistent result. Running the code with the same input at different times can result in different output. I cannot tell if this could occur, or if it would be an issue.

Another potential issue is that you are writing to a 24 bit per pixel image. This means that pixels will not be 4-byte aligned. I *think* writes should still be atomic, and thus thread safe. But I'm fairly sure that it will at least hurt performance, since CPUs like to track memory in larger chunks, and operations that cross chunk boundaries tend to suffer. So I would at least try using bgra, (i.e. 32 bits per pixel that aligns better) as the output format and in the `rgb` image and see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track by using Parallel.For, which allows you to utilize multiple processor cores for the loop, leading to faster execution. However, there are a few things you can consider to make the code more efficient.

Avoid async inside Parallel.For: There's usually no need to use async inside a Parallel.For loop, unless you're performing some asynchronous I/O operations within the loop. Removing the unnecessary async should improve performance.

Avoid unnecessary array accesses: Every time you do X[i, j].Intensity or similar operations, you're performing an array access, which has overhead. Instead, consider caching the value in a local variable.

Correct the loop size: You have size - 0, which is just size.